# How do I attach custom transformers to a compiler host?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a custom TypeScript watcher that looks something like:

```js
const compilerHost = typescript.createWatchCompilerHost(config.fileNames, config.options, typescript.sys, undefined, reportDiagnostic)
typescript.createWatchProgram(compilerHost)
```

I want to hook up a custom transformer that is used when the watcher compiles my `.ts` files.  If I was doing a one-time compile, I would do something like this, supplying the transformer as the last parameter.

```js
const program = typescript.createProgram(config.fileNames, config.options)
const emitResult = program.emit(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, { before: [ transformer(program) ] })
```

However, I cannot find any way to add the transformer to either the compiler host or the watch program creation.

How can I add a custom transformer to a watch compiler host?

One way to do it in theory would be to supply a custom `CreateProgram` to the `createWatchCompilerHost` that has the `emit` function on the returned objects overriden with my custom transformer.  I'm unclear on how realistic that path would be though and am looking for a better option.

Answer (score 0):

The following is functional (for my case), but I'm not a big fan of it.  Would love to see some better answers.

```js
const compilerHost = typescript.createWatchCompilerHost(config.fileNames, config.options, typescript.sys, undefined, reportDiagnostic)
const originalAfterProgramCreate = compilerHost.afterProgramCreate
compilerHost.afterProgramCreate = builderProgram => {
    const originalEmit = builderProgram.emit
    builderProgram.emit = (targetSourceFile, writeFile, cancellationToken, emitOnlyDtsFiles, customTransformers): typescript.EmitResult => {
        const transformers = customTransformers || { before: [] }
        if (!transformers.before) transformers.before = []
        transformers.before.push(myTransformer(builderProgram.getProgram()))
        return originalEmit(targetSourceFile, writeFile, cancellationToken, emitOnlyDtsFiles, transformers)
    }
    if (originalAfterProgramCreate) originalAfterProgramCreate(builderProgram)
}
typescript.createWatchProgram(compilerHost)
```